# ngStorage $sessionStorage is undefined when accessing from new tab angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am new to AngularJS and need help, I am using angular's ngStorage and I am storing my objects data into $sessionStorage and then I open a new form programatically and there I want to access that $sessionStorage value, but unfortunately I cannot access value there it shows undefined when I access value in another controller.

Here is first controllers code:

```
smartApp.controller('mainController', function ($scope, $sessionStorage) {

   $scope.generateInvoice = function () {

        var promisesInvoice = assetRentService.getInvoice();
        promisesInvoice.then(function (result) {

              $sessionStorage.currentInvoice = result.data;
              $window.open($rootScope.baseUrlMain+"#/invoice", '_blank');

            }

        }, function (err) {
       //log errors here

        }).finally(function () {
            //finally block
        });
    };       

});
```

But when new tab is opened this $sessionStorage is undefined in that tab, although the browser shows that $sessionStorage has value,

```
$scope.monthlyAssetItemRentInvoiceList = []
smartApp.controller('printController', function ($scope, $sessionStorage) {
    $scope.monthlyAssetItemRentInvoiceList = $sessionStorage.currentInvoice;
});
```

And here in this Print controller it shows $sessionStorage is undefined, what could be the issue, how can I solve this issue, One more thing to say, my clients requirement is to open new tab and show data there, kindly help me in this.

Comment: $localStorage should work if the base url is same. Can you please provide a minimal coded  working jsFiddle or Codepen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
smartApp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {

  $scope.generateInvoice = function() {

    var promisesInvoice = assetRentService.getInvoice();
    promisesInvoice.then(function(result) {

          localStorage.currentInvoice = JSON.stringify(result.data);
          $window.open($rootScope.baseUrlMain + "#/invoice", '_blank');

        }

      },
      function(err) {
        //log errors here

      }).finally(function() {
    //finally block
  });
};

});




$scope.monthlyAssetItemRentInvoiceList = []
smartApp.controller('printController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.monthlyAssetItemRentInvoiceList = JSON.parse(localStorage.currentInvoice);
    console.log($scope.monthlyAssetItemRentInvoiceList);
});

/*localStorage is associated to window.But you can use $localStorage to avoid, JSON.parse and stringify
.I am trying to show you, that localStorage is available across window*/
```

Answer (score 0):

The main reason behind your problem is that you are trying to transfer data between two browser tabs using angular `$sessionStorage`. But the main thing you have to understand is that `$sessionStorage` is binded with the tabs of browser. That is the values stored in the `$sessionStorage` can be accessed only within a browser tab. Inorder to achieve this requirement you can either user cookie storage, local storage or even angular services to transfer data between controllers.

Comment: $localStorage is also not working, and I have tested service even still that is not working what could be that issue?

Comment: Please try cookie storage if local storage is not working. In my openion $localStorage is the best option for your question and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

$sessionStorage will be available to current window(window session) only.you must use $localStorage to transfer between window tabs.

Comment: $localStorage is not working i have test that as well

Comment: try adding some value in localstorage in browser manually and open new tab in browser and check,that value will be there